# How can I turn a span9 into a span12 on smaller browser windows?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout as follows:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="span9" ></div> <div class="span3" ></div>
</div>
```

I would like the span9 div and the span3 div to both become span12 divs when the user is viewing the page on a tablet or mobile device, and I would like them to become vertically stacked above on another.

Can this be accomplished and if so how? My current solution relies upon a second set of divs which I show on small browser windows and I hide the above divs.

Answer (score 3):

Using Bootstrap 3, this is super easy:

```
<div class="col-md-9">...</div>
<div class="col-md-3">...</div>
```

At typical desktop resolution (> 992px), the divs will be 9/12 columns & 3/12 columns. On anything smaller, they will be 12/12.

[Twitter Bootstrap 3 grids](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

---

Using Bootstrap 2.3.2, you can add a media query:

```
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
  .span9, .span3 {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```